# How to set up diffrent mobile theme for single site in Wordpress?

Tags: theme-development

I have a site in Wordpress with few pages. One of them should have a diffrent theme than rest of webpages. I know how to do it with desktop, but i don't know what i should set up to obtain the same for mobile.

Comment: How do you have your site and pages setup now?  "I know how to do it with desktop"  How would you do that?

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress uses something called [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).  These allow you to apply different look for a page or group of pages.

You can apply CSS specifically for that page template and use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to effect mobile.

If you can provide more specific detail about your setup I can give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I'll check out this solution tommorow.